# Is there a way to prevent HTTP resolved urls in package-lock.json?

Tags: npm

In a recent PR I was reviewing the package-lock.json had the following diff:

```
- "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/sax/-/sax-1.2.1.tgz",
+ "resolved": "http://registry.npmjs.org/sax/-/sax-1.2.1.tgz",
```

Is there a way to prevent insecure urls in package-lock.json?